# getting error when clicking a button by javaScript to call codeBehind function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, code-behind

I need to call some codeBehind function from JavaScript. For this, I have a hidden button (`asp:Button`).

When I click this button from javaScript like:

```
var btn = document.getElementById("btnHidden");
btn.click();
```

I got an error:

```
System.Web.HttpException: The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted.
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: <asp:Button style="display:none"> </asp:Button>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i tried like this and is working

### aspx

```
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function btnClick()
        {
            alert("clicked!!!");

            var btn=document.getElementById('<%=Button1.ClientID%>');
            btn.click();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        test page
        <input type="button" id="btn" onclick="btnClick()" value="Click" />

        <asp:Button ID="Button1" style="display:none" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

### aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

In the first button client click i tried to raise the second button click event.

Answer (score 1):

first you have to hide this button with css not server side , i mean `display:none` not `Visible=false;`

like this :

```
Button1.Attributes.CssAttributes.Add("Display","None");
```

then you should use `ClientID`

```
document.getElementById('<%=Button1.ClientID%>').click();
```

try to set `UseSubmitBehaviour=false` on button

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your Web.config file:

```
<pages validateRequest="false" enableEventValidation="false" viewStateEncryptionMode ="Never">
```

Check this [blog](http://renditionprotocol.blogspot.in/2007/01/state-information-is-invalid-for-this.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this,

var btn = document.getElementById('<%= btnHidden.ClientID %>').value;